# Force liquibase to change changeSet checksum

Tags: liquibase

I have some advanced scenario where I need to drop index and then create it again. Unfortunately some changes were made and they are producing another problem.

for better imagination here's structure of what I want to do:

```
databaseChangeLog:
- dropUniqueConstraintChangeSet -> new changeSet
- dropIndexChangeSet -> new changeSet
- addUniqueConstraintChangeSet -> existing changeSet (need to add preconditions + change checkSum)
```

Here's detail:
My current situation is that I have changeSets which are adding unique constraint (call it `addUniqueConstraintChangeSet`. I'd like to add dropUniqueConstraint (call it  `dropUniqueConstraintChangeSet`) + dropIndex (call it `dropIndexChangeSet`) changeSets before those changeSets to ensure some database policies (mainly oracle with it's ORA-02429 error). I also want to change the `addUniqueConstraintChangeSet` and add some preconditions to ensure it will be executed only in case when it's allowed to. However the problem is that I'm not able to change the checkSum of it.

Is there any way to modify the checksum? I've tried to add `empty` change but that didn't changed the checkSum.

Comment: Have you tried adding `<validCheckSum>ANY</validCheckSum>`?

Comment: I guess no, because checksum won't change and it won't be executed. But seems like adding empty works. Maybe I just tested it somehow wrong.